# Association Exclude Based on Field

Tags: ruby, associations, models

I'm looking for the best Ruby way to accomplish this.

I have a `Person` that `has_many` `Feeds` `through` `Subscriptions`. So we can do things like `Person.feeds`, and it gets all the feeds a person is subscribed to.

Problem is, subscriptions are either authorized or deauthorized. What is the best way to make `Person.feeds` respect the Authorized `status` bit on the `Subscription` model?

So we can do something like `Person.feeds.where(:status => authorized)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this with a command like the following:

```
@person.feeds.joins(:subscription).where(subscriptions: { status: 'authorized' })
```

N.B. the `joins` takes the association's format, singular in this case, while `where` takes the table name, typically pluralised.

What this does in order is:

- Loads the `feeds` belonging to a `person`
- Joins these feeds to their `subscription`
- Queries the `subscriptions` table to return only the feeds where the subscription is active

To refactor this, I'd include a couple of methods in the relevant models:

```
# feed.rb
scope :active, -> { joins(:subscription).where(subscriptions: { status: 'authorized' }) } 

# person.rb
def active_feeds
  feeds.active
end
```

Then, you can just call `@person.active_feeds` to get the results you want from anywhere in your code base.

(There's also the added bonus of `Feed.active` being available anywhere should you wish to display active feeds outside of a user's scope.)

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what we need. One thing I'm confused about is when I call my person.active_feeds it is returning a ton of the same feed records? I am fixing this by just adding a .unique on the end, but any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Huh, unusual - could you post the SQL that's generated? Also, you could add `unique` into the scope of that keeps things cleaner. Glad to have helped anyway!

Comment: SELECT 
    `feeds`.*
FROM
    `feeds`
        INNER JOIN
    `subscriptions` `subscriptions_feeds` ON `subscriptions_feeds`.`feed_id` = `feeds`.`id`
        INNER JOIN
    `subscriptions` ON `feeds`.`id` = `subscriptions`.`feed_id`
WHERE
    `feeds`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
        AND `subscriptions`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
        AND `subscriptions`.`subscriber_id` = 61949
        AND `subscriptions`.`status` = 'AUTHORIZED'
        AND (feeds.tenant_id = 88)
        AND (subscriptions.tenant_id = 88);

Comment: Ah, looks like there's another step in connecting the tables due to your setup. I'd say it justifies a new question if you'd like, on how to optimise the tables' setup and the query itself. If you'd like, @ me on there I'll see how I can help.

Comment: Gotcha.. Based on that query any advise on where I could add some indexes to make this query faster? It's timing out on our server at the moment :(